# Class method not working in Selenium

Tags: python, class, selenium, methods

I am new to Python and `Selenium webdriver` and I am having troubles when trying to call the following class method in another script :

```
class SharedTestSteps():
  def SharedLogin(self, login, password, getsubmit):
    self.login = self.driver.find_element_by_id('loginField')
    self.password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('passwordField')
    self.login.send_keys("joe")
    self.password.send_keys("password")
    self.getsubmit = self.driver.find_element_by_id('loginSubmitButton')
```

When I run the script I get the following message stating that nothing has happened :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: you are sending the keys but not 'logging in' try to end the password with a `\n` or maybe click on the submit/log in button?

Comment: also, please post the code which is calling that method

Comment: Hi @pyjg the code that calls the method in the other script is the following:

    **from Book_Job import SharedTestSteps**

Comment: are you calling the `SharedLogin` function anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes below.....


        SharedTestSteps.SharedLogin()

Comment: have a `print("in shared Login")` as your first line in the `SharedLogin` function and run the code again and post what happens

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Comment: you do not get the print? that means your function isnt being called.

Comment: Yes, I cannot figure out why the class method is not being called plus also it does not get picked up in the script the class method is in.

Comment: please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @pyjg I have found another way to do this by creating a temp file with the text and then calling that temp file later.